# How can I view PDF bleedbox, cropbox, trimbox, etc?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

How can I view PDF bleedboxes and trimboxes on Ubuntu, like I can in Adobe Acrobat Pro? I would like to do so without resorting to a Virtual Machine or WINE.

Example:
[image]

The green mark is the trimbox. What piece of software do I need for Ubuntu to show them like this?

Comment: [Gtumbler available for Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/gtumbler-graphical-pdf-manager-for-ubuntu.html#comments) but unfortunately not for newer version :(

Comment: @KasiyA does it run on Ubuntu 14.04/14.10, even without the repository?

Comment: No, I tried it. It's also not available in software center.

Comment: @jtg why not using [acrobat reader](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-adobe-reader-ubuntu-14-10/)?

Comment: @KasiyA Acrobat reader doesn't show fonts and stuff properly, also the printbox/bleedbox/trimbox stuff is a Adobe Pro feature, not available in reader.

Comment: For reference: this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13240546/1154487) explains what are those boxes.

Comment: I have to put this as comment.. Foxit, if you want to pay money. I believe it has a 30 trial too, seems to let you edit bleedbox colors. PDFedit, if you want to script it looks like it's really powerful, especially with knowledge. (I remember using it and it was too much for me)I like MasterPDF Editor, but I do not see a spot to view the boxes, for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to [Phoenix87](https://askubuntu.com/users/72484/phoenix87) (the creator and maintainer of Gtumbler), a new stable release is now available from his PPA:

```
$ wget https://launchpad.net/~phoenix1987/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/gtumbler_1.0-0ubuntu3_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i gtumbler_1.0-0ubuntu3_all.deb
$ rm gtumbler_1.0-0ubuntu3_all.deb
```

See [his blog post](http://thenestofheliopolis.blogspot.fr/2016/06/the-nest-of-heliopolis-ppa-repository.html#gtumbler) for more details.

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I've also found the Gtumbler [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~phoenix1987/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and I think this is the only app able to display those boxes. Problem is that this ppa only contains builds for 12.04.

I've been looking at both the [bzr branches](https://code.launchpad.net/~phoenix1987) and the [tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/~phoenix1987/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/gtumbler_12.07.7.tar.gz) of Gtumbler, both differ but it seems that even if older the package code is more reliable.

So I decided to remove the following deprecated dependencies and the corresponding calls in the app (changes are available [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sylvain-pineau/gtumbler/trunk/revision/29)):

- python-launchpad-integration
- desktopcouch
- python-desktopcouch-records
- python-desktopcouch-application
- pdfedit

The only regression is that you're unable to save your preferences. So all those settings are now hardcoded in the application. They are not so many though:

```
preferences = {
    'cb_box0'                   : '#A020F0',
    'cb_box1'                   : '#FF0000',
    'cb_box2'                   : '#0000FF',
    'cb_box3'                   : '#00FF00',
    'cb_box4'                   : '#4D4D4D',

    'cbo_editor'                : 0,
    'cbo_compatibility'         : 2,

    'chk_convert'               : True,
    'chk_create_copy'           : True,
    'chk_crop_create_copy'      : True,
    'chk_display_path'          : True,
    'chk_open_cat'              : False,

    'rdo_viewer_default'        : True,
    'rdo_viewer_custom'         : False,

    'txt_other_tool'            : '',
    'txt_tool_args'             : '',
    'txt_viewer_custom'         : '',
    }
```

The result are new builds available in my [ppa](https://code.launchpad.net/~sylvain-pineau/+archive/ubuntu/gtumbler/) for 14.04, 14.10 and 15.04.
To install and run `gtumbler` on 14.10 type the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sylvain-pineau/gtumbler
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtumbler
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/gtumbler/bin/gtumbler
```

Then open a pdf by clicking on the + icon and all the defined boxes should be displayed in the preview window:

[image]

Comment: Wow, just wow. I will definitely have to try this tonight when I get home. :-D

Comment: Wow!  I'm not even going to *look* for another solution!  ;-) Félicitations!

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot for this. I didn't have the time to push an update so far (I also got the app running at the moment with the same tweak). I might start working on this app again though. In the meantime thanks for making it available to newer ubuntu versions! :D

Comment: @Phoenix87 I only re-packaged it, I saw that you've started another branch (more recent, without desktopcouch IIRC). It's a great application, congrats.

Comment: A new stable release is now available from my PPA. It brings support for user preferences back in with GSettings, plus some other bugfixes. See http://thenestofheliopolis.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/the-nest-of-heliopolis-ppa-repository.html for more details.

Comment: @Phoenix87 Many thanks, I've updated my answer to point to your ppa first.

Comment: @SylvainPineau I've started a Python 3 fork at https://github.com/Hierosoft/gtumbler. There is not a copy of gtumbler on Gabriele N. Tornetta's sizeable GitHub account (https://github.com/P403n1x87) but maybe he will see that I converted the repo from bazaar format. I am still figuring out the authorship and I don't know of any other source for the code other than launchpad (bazaar format). Any help with gathering history such as authors and links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Acrobat Pro 8.0 working under Wine on openSUSE 11.4](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/459512-How-To-get-Adobe-Acrobat-Pro-8-0-working-under-Wine-on-openSUSE-11-4/)

you can try that. and if it doesnt work i will show you how i got it on mine.

Comment: Does this work with a CreativeCloud account?

Comment: it is worth a try.